# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac1n \sum\limits_{k=1}^nn^{1/k}=2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Prove that $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac1n \sum\limits_{k=1}^nn^{1/k}=2$$

How to estimate the sum? I tried to use Stolz's theorem but it is still a similar summation.

Comment: This is wrong: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}n^{1/k}\ge n^{1/1}+\sum_{k=2}^{n}1=2n-1.$$

Comment: @ProfessorVector Oh, sorry. I have corrected the range of summation, which begins at 2.

Comment: It's still wrong in the title of your question.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Either slow down... or take things in your own hands by correcting the typos. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

Using the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality

$$1 \leqslant n^{1/k} = (\underbrace{1 \cdot 1 \cdots 1}_{\text{k-2 times}} \sqrt{n} \sqrt{n})^{1/k} \leqslant \frac{1}{k} (k-2 + 2\sqrt{n}) = 1 + \frac{2(\sqrt{n}-1)}{k}$$

Sum on $2\leqslant k\leqslant n$ and apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Nice, +1. $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did:  Thanks for adding that crucial $2 \leqslant k \leqslant n$.

Comment: How does adding and dividing by $n$ leads to limit $2$? Shouldn't it lead to $1$?

Comment: Got it that extra $1$ comes from $k=1$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: $n- 1 \leqslant \sum_{k=2}^n n^{1/k} \leqslant \ldots$ and $2n- 1 \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^n n^{1/k} \leqslant \ldots$

Comment: +1 already for the very smart use of AM GM. I wonder how much powerful the simple inequality is.