# Limit of $(n+n^{1/2}+\cdots+n^{1/n})/n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm pretty sure this has been asked here before. But perhaps due to high flexibility in formulating this problem I couldn't find any useful resources.

Obviously a lower bound is $2$. And, numerically testing it in WolframAlpha, I'm quite convinced the limit should just be $2$.

My first thought was to see it as a Riemann partial sum but it failed, at least in the equi-partition case.

Could anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2450093/148510

Comment: @RRL: your duplicate is a duplicate!

Comment: @RRL thanks much!

Comment: @RRL technically finding a lower bound isn't that hard or meaningful, for example, $-1$ is also a lower bound. It's just this lower bound happens to be *the* lower bound. :)